# Node.JS cluster to build a single node project on a multi core server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

I'm new to Node.JS and I want to understand how this engine work and how to use it to obtain performance and speed.
I'm building a big website using Node.JS (with Express exc...) but I'm worried about what I have found: I read that Javascript uses only a single thread to work and that is better to start multiple node instance instead of a single node that do all the work.

Node.JS has been updated and now it support parallelization and clustering to do all the work always exploiting maximum performance. But I am a bit skeptical about this.

Yesterday I have modified my node and I have activated the cluster mode activating all threads on my server.

Probably the performance are better but I want to know what happen if I build all my website using a single node instance with this configuration. NodeJS is perfect for organizing modules and controllers (in blocks) and we can build a great and well-organized program using a single node.
But performance? Is the single Thread problem solved using clustering and load balancing?

Thanks for you support :)

Answer (score 0):

Just host your Node JS project on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) and you can choose how many instances of your application you want, or host in [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) and it will scale it automatically for you if you start to receive multiple requests at the same time.

[Cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) will do what you want, but it's usually not worth it, unless you're an infra guy setting up the servers.